# How to implement previous- and next-links in the object-detail-view of a search-result?

Tags: django

I am almost done with my first production-ready django-project. I got one big problem left: 
I got an article-search-view that renders a list of found articles. Pagination is working just fine for the resultlist. When I click on the article-title the object-detail-page opens. What I want: previous- and next-result-links on the object-detail-page.

I tried several approaches to similar problems but didn't find a working solution. If I try to use a paginator with only one article (for the object-detail-page) I need to know that paginator-index in the resultlist. But how?

Even the .get_next(previous)_by_foo-Method is not really usable in this scenario AFAICT. Or am I missing something obvious here? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you want but it seems that basic python can solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Paginator from django works with lists. A way of searching indexes in lists it's like that:

```
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'].index('bbb') # result: 1
```

or so like this:

```
model = object()
[object(), object(), model].index(model) # result: 2
```

Hope that gives you a hint on how you find paginator-index on your list.

Comment: Main reason why people use pagination is not-loading-all-objects-from-database-into-list. Next object should be selected with an sql query, which in django will look like: `filter(id__gt=current_obj.id).order('id')[0]`.

Comment: @Guilherme: Thanks but I doubt that this may be sufficient. The thing is: Pagination A shows 10 items, Pagination B only 1 for one and the same list of objects. In Pagination A I need a Pagination-B-link for every item. So I have to search through the index of Pagination B for every object in Pagination A. This relationship must be given to the template. So in the end I can write (in the template):{% for a in A %} { b.index }{% endfor %}.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a link, at object-details-page, to next item from search-result, you must get next item from the search-result. To get a next item you need to perform the same search query which was executed in search-page and apply some extra filters to get only the next item from that list. But here you have a problem: you only have object-id in object-details page, you don't have the `search-term`. Without search-term you won't be able to create the search-query. That means you need to get search-term somehow. How do you get that search-term? You need to pass it from the search-result-page somehow. You can save the search-term in session/cookie, or, maybe better: you can pass it via a GET parameter to object-details page. Now when you search-term in object-display page, you can perform a search-query, and from that query you can select the next and the previous objects.

I think now you should be able to implement that. If not you could show some of your code of object-details view, maybe someone will write some code for you.

Comment: Yes and that was exactly what started to confuse me. I was hoping for an easier way. And I may have found it myself: The "get_next_by_foo"-Method takes a list as filter where to look for "next_by_foo". So I have to pass my resultlist as parameter. My search-results are preordered by date anyway.

Comment: Well, I had to include the get-parameters nevertheless as you may have already expected. At least without using sessions/cookies to save the resultlist. And I am still a little unsatisfied with all the actual DB-Requests. But at least I got it working now. I didn`t get the pagination-alternative to do what I want. So thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you could use this

```
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next &raquo;</a>
<a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">&laquo; previous</a>
```